# C++ compile time dispatch abstraction?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct object1 {
    object1(int v) : type(1), value(v) {}

    int type;
    int value;
};

struct object2 {
    object2(int v) : type(2), value(v) {}

    int type;
    int value;
};

template <typename HeaderType>
void foo(HeaderType * hdr) {
    std::cout << "foo called with type " << hdr->type << " and value " << hdr->value << std::endl;
}

// this function doesn't work
template <typename HandlerType>
void dispatch(int type, int val, HandlerType handler) {
    if (type == 1) {
        object1 h(val);
        handler(&h);
    } else {
        object2 h(val);
        handler(&h);
    }
}

int main() {
    int type = 1;
    int val = 1;

    // this part works
    if (type == 1) {
        object1 h(val);
        foo(&h);
    } else {
        object2 h(val);
        foo(&h);
    }

    // trying to replicate the above behavior in a more abstract way,
    // ideally via a function call of the following sort
    //
    // dispatch(type, val, ..foo..? );
}
```

The above program takes an input value, uses it to decide what type of object to create, then calls a function foo with a pointer to that object.

Question: Is it possible to create this sort of abstraction where the caller of dispatch doesn't know the exact types that foo will be called with but the dispatch function doesn't know the specific function that is going to be called?

Comment: So you create an object on the stack and return its address to a handler and are wondering why its not working?

Comment: `dispatch(type, val, [](auto a) {return foo(a);} );` maybe?

Comment: Sounds like the Visitor pattern.

Comment: @newone, As long as the object is guaranteed to stay alive - as it is here - that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @newone the stack object stays in scope until the handler is done running. Obviously the handler needs to know to not copy that pointer anywhere else.

Comment: @cpplearner Is that a C++14 generic lambda?

Comment: I experimented a little bit and it looks like it can't be done since c++ doesn't have reflection and the type needs to be known one way or another. Even if you use void* you'll have to know what kind of data type is expected. You can always use dispatch(type, val, &foo<Base>); but thats not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
template <typename HandlerType>
void dispatch(int type, int val, HandlerType handler) {
    if (type == 1) {
        object1 h1(val);
        handler(&h1);
    } else {
        object2 h2(val);
        handler(&h2);
    }
}
```

All branches should be valid, so `handler(&h1)` and `handler(&h2)` should be valid calls.

For that, `handler` may be a generic lambda (since C++14) as suggested in comment:

```
dispatch(type, val, [](auto a) {return foo(a);} );
```

or you may create your own functor:

```
struct foo_caller
{
    template <typename HeaderType>
    void operator () (const HeaderType* hdr) const {
        std::cout << "foo called with type " << hdr->type << " and value " << hdr->value << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And then call it:

```
dispatch(type, val, foo_caller());
```

Comment: The pre-C++14 functor method isn't particularly pretty, but it more or less does what I need. That the method is forwards compatible with the generic lambda syntax is convenient as well, as that seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!